# SQL Server : how to get unknown number of fields as column name?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that is populated with data via an API. I can not change the layout of the data coming in.

I get the data in the following layout:

```
elementtype | elementid | groupkeyword | keyword | name   | type     | value | options

event       | 2644-1523 | algemeneinfo | artiest  | art   |  text    | test1 | NULL
event       | 2644-1523 | algemeneinfo | titel    | tit   |  text    | test2 | "OK"
event       | 2644-1523 | algemeneinfo | startuur | start | datetime | 20:00 | NULL
event       | 2644-1523 | algemeneinfo | einduur  | eind  | datetime | 22:00 | NULL
...         |...        |...           |...       |..     |...       |...    |...
```

I would want the table to have this layout:

```
elementid | artiest | titel | startuur | einduur |...

2644-1523 | test1   | test2 | 20:00    | 22:00   |...
```

It can be in another table created especially for this format.

The number of values in the 'keyword' column can differ with every 'id'. So sometimes there are 200 'keywords' and sometimes there are 240 'keywords'

I have tried the pivot function, but it won't work. I also read this isn't the ideal way to go.

I do not know the code that gets the data into the table.

I read that in the dynamic pivot table, all fields that become column names need to be specified. So do i need to specify +-240 column names?

A query I use to get all the data is:

```
SELECT [elementtype]
      ,[elementid]
      ,[groupkeyword]
      ,[keyword]
      ,[name]
      ,[type]
      ,[value]
      ,[options]
  FROM [dbo].[CustomdataElement]
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

I erased the query I already tried because it wouldn't work, I based it on the following code:

```
create table temp
(
    date datetime,
    category varchar(3),
    amount money
)

insert into temp values ('1/1/2012', 'ABC', 1000.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'DEF', 500.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'GHI', 800.00)
insert into temp values ('2/10/2012', 'DEF', 700.00)
insert into temp values ('3/1/2012', 'ABC', 1100.00)


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT date, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , category
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
```

there are about 28000 different (elementid's) with each +-240 (keywords). there are +-10 (elementid's) added every day.

Comment: Please don't post links to pages with images on them. Provide your data as formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements. Users are unlikely to visit an off site resource, and that is much more likely when the resource is an image; which we can't use. Take the time to format your post so that it's useful to the volunteers please. Thanks.

Comment: ok thanx i'll edit

Comment: Looks like you required `Dynamic PIVOT`. Search for that, you will get lots of thread on that

Comment: @squirrel sorry i'm a beginner and i read up about this but i cant get this to work. I also read that the (dynamic) pivot functions aren't really very performant.

Comment: please post the query you have tried

Comment: How many different keywords you have in total? 240? 28000? 240*28000? Your task is not SQL-friendly at all; likely it would be easier to pivot your data at client side.

Comment: @Arvo I have 28000 elementid's with each +-240 'keywords' so 240*28000. So propably ask developer that created service to populate the table to integrate this into the service?

Comment: Who needs to see your pivoted version? Human, using some kind of web application? Another computer system? As you can see yourselves, you can't create universal table with millions of columns. You can of course create procedure, which returns all keywords as columns for specific element id - this is likely what human would like to see (this is dynamic pivot approach like described in answers).

Comment: @Arvo Im better in explaining it p2p and showing it live. I will ask The programmer because it really is to complicated for me I think. Thanx everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dynamic Pivot` can do this in a better way. As Suggested by Squirrel. But any kind of suggestion or improvement will be appreciated.
Try This:

```
create table #temp
(
    element_id datetime,
    element_info varchar(25), //Max value can be according to your need.
    value varchar(50) //Max value can be according to your need.
)

insert into #temp values (2644414721-1559139530, 'algementinfo_aantalgebruikarslokaal','test1')
insert into #temp values (2644414721-1559139530, 'algementinfo_aantalgebruikarslokaal','test2')

insert into #temp values (2644414721-1559139530, 'algementinfo_aantalgebruikarslokaal','test3')

insert into #temp values (2644414721-1559139530, 'algementinfo_aantalgebruikarslokaal','test4')

insert into #temp values (2644414721-1559139530, 'algementinfo_aantalgebruikarslokaal','test5')

insert into #temp values (2644414721-1559139530, 'algementinfo_aantalgebruikarslokaal','test6')

//Change all remaining element_id & info as i've done first one for you!

DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(elemnent_info) + ',' FROM (select distinct element_info from #temp ) as tmp
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end

set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(
    select element_id,element_info, value from #temp
) src
pivot 
(   //Here aggregate function can be used to of your choice. I'm using Max
    max(amount) for category in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

execute(@query)
drop table #temporary
```

Comment: is it a problem that 'elementid' is variable? I have more than 28000 different 'elementid's and each 'elementid' has +- 240 'keywords'. every day there are +-10 elementid's added

Comment: This makes it much to complicated for me. Probably best to ask the developer who made the service that populates the table to integrate this in the service?

Comment: If your elementid is vairable you may use `cursors` to fetch one row at a time `OR` `T-SQL` to fetch all rows, in the `INSERT INTO` query part, and apply these queries on them!